# How to create Custom ng-repeat without using angular.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json, html

I am trying get data from server with json and manupulate it to html.This will be really hard to write and really unclear to understand when I scan my code again if I write it on javascript because I will get data and use jquery append to append data to html element and I should add a lot of html inline.For example:

```
 $.getJSON( "json.php", function( json ) {


 $.each( json, function( key, data ) {


 $('#content').append('<a href="www.example.com" ><li class="class" id="id" >+data.type+</li></a><a href="www.example.com" ><li class="class1" id="id2" >+data.type1+</li></a><a href="www.example.com" ><li class="a" id="id3" >+data.type2+</li></a><a href="www.example.com" ><li class="d" id="id4" >+data.type3+</li></a><a href="www.example.com"><li class="h" id="id5" >+data.type4+</li></a><a href="www.example.com" ><li class="fg" id="id6" >+data.typ5e+</li></a><a href="www.example.com" ><li class="gfh" id="id7" >+data.type6+</li></a><a href="www.example.com" ><li class="example213" id="id8" >+data.typ7e+</li></a>');
enter code here
```

Imagine It will be more more big than this and I should write a lot of inline html in javascript and It will be incredible unreadable.Solution is Angular.js ng-repeat beacause I can write noormal html which is easy to read for all developers andd easy to write but I dont want to use angular.js beacuse It is slow,It contain a lot of bytes and I only want to use two of its method (ng-repeat with databinds).How can I achive this?

Comment: Numerous templating libraries around

Comment: @charlietfl Can you give a example to solve this problem similar like angular.js?

Comment: Did you search for templating libraries? The examples will all be there within each site

Comment: @charlietfl I searched a lot but I always find something contain angular.js library

Comment: Must not be searching properly https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+template+library&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Comment: Can you give me a example that you use on your projects for that kind of problems?@charlietfl

Comment: Unless you're running through massive amounts of data or are worried about microseconds of response time angular.js done properly isn't that slow.  That said, like the above commentators have pointed out, templating libraries.

Comment: @Thecor thank you for your answer.Yes I am running massive amout of data and that's why it is realy hard to write.But problem is I dont need angular.js because I dont use it,I want to use only 2 part of it(databind and ng-repeat with ng-if) and I think download whole library for only this purpose is just extra load time for website.Can you give me example templating library or ways that you use on that kind of problems?

Comment: Gave you link that shows numerous libraries and blog posts about them. What did you try?

Comment: @charlietfl I watched a lot of them.There are really useful maybe I will use them on my project but I cant find solution about this problem.OK there are solutions but not al of them only can be wroten in javascipt which will make my codes unreadable because there really big amout of html and I should manupulate data into it and then append dom

Comment: Not sure what magic answer you are looking for. You can also use php to template the html and insert that

Comment: @charlietfl yes I had done it before but It is heavy,and json data is fast and recommended.Now I am just trying to get json and parse it with way that will be clear and also readable for other developers.For Now I just have done it with json with only jquery append and there are a lot of bugs design problems,and unreadable content.Only html part of data is 940 line of code.It is really hard to read on javascript.I am searching for way that I can get data with json and easily parse it html like angular.js repeat or that kind of way.

Comment: And that is exactly what template libraries are used for.

Comment: @charlietfl Ok which one I can use can you give me an example that will be useful like angular.js ng-repeat?

Comment: A day ago I provided link in google that outlines numerous ones. Try a few to see what fits you best. That's simply how web development works.

Comment: @charlietfl I found handbar.js which use in this case maybe I will use it sometimes but I found better.I actually wanted to use handlebar.js but on my project there are a lot of if/else statement which is hard to use on handlebar .Better way is on below just quite simple. Write \ tag to end of line and this will be pretty useful just like html also without extra template loading.Everything from scratch is fast and clear,and help me create more creative things:).

Comment: All template engines have if/else

Comment: @charlietfl All template engines have if else but they cant change variables or use exactly javascript which I exactly need.Anyway,Ok I find way but in all ways json somehow is slow than html even it contain less kb than html?How it is possible?

Comment: Can't just compare the data..have to also consider the processing. Could be inefficient methods used for insertion / parsing etc

Comment: @charlietfl In your opinion,Which one suggested for big amount of data ?html response or json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found pretty simple way and without any template library.Just write \ tag end of each line ,native,very simple and readable.In my case I have a lot of if else statement,a lot of adding new variables, that why I cant use angular or that kind of thing and I will simply use \ tag just break line.